# Npm packages are not installed by usimg NPM install command

Tags: angular, angular5, npm-install, npm-start

I am working on a project based on Angular5. I need to set up an Angular5 code. When I open my code in visual studio code and try to install the packages by using the "NPM Install" command.

I am using Angular 5 and CLI version is "1.2.5".

I am attaching the error that I am getting.

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.1/node-v64-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.16.3 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.16.3 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp ERR! Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file
gyp gypERR! configure error
 ERR! gypconfigure error
ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  stackstack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
 Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  stackstack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  stackstack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp gypERR!  ERR!stack      at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  stackSystem     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
 Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gypgyp  ERR! ERR!System  Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gypcommand "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=D:\\Suraj\\kjhdfgjlh\\eco\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=D:\\Suraj\\kjhdfgjlh\\eco\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown"
 gyp ERR! cwdERR! D:\Suraj\kjhdfgjlh\eco\node_modules\grpc
 gypcommand  "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=D:\\Suraj\\kjhdfgjlh\\eco\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=D:\\Suraj\\kjhdfgjlh\\eco\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown"
ERR!gyp  ERR!node -v  v10.16.3
gypcwd  D:\Suraj\kjhdfgjlh\eco\node_modules\grpc
gypERR!  node-gyp -vERR! v3.8.0
 gyp node -vERR! v10.16.3
gyp  not okERR!
 node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=D:\Suraj\kjhdfgjlh\eco\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=D:\Suraj\kjhdfgjlh\eco\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Suraj\kjhdfgjlh\eco\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Suraj\\kjhdfgjlh\\eco\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\Suraj\kjhdfgjlh\eco\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=D:\Suraj\kjhdfgjlh\eco\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=D:\Suraj\kjhdfgjlh\eco\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
> node-sass@4.9.2 install D:\Suraj\kjhdfgjlh\eco\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js
Cached binary found at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.9.2\win32-x64-64_binding.node
> node-sass@4.9.2 postinstall D:\Suraj\kjhdfgjlh\eco\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js
Binary found at D:\Suraj\kjhdfgjlh\eco\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-64\binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall D:\Suraj\kjhdfgjlh\eco\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: grpc@1.10.1 (node_modules\grpc):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Are you sure you are typing `npm install` not `NPM Install` which you have written, cos that is wrong? Right one is I just mentioned `npm install`

Comment: @Alok, I have written npm install only.

Comment: Error: Can't find Python executable - can you check your local python version. And is it on windows PATH?

Comment: @Sam. Could you please tell me how can I check the Python version as I am not sure about this?

Comment: `python --version` in command line